# ¿La diferencia entre «se llama» y «se le llama»?

Tags: pronombres, objetos-indirectos, reflexivos, voz-pasiva, oraciones-pasivas-reflejas

¿Qúe diferencia hay entre estas dos frases por ejemplo:

- «Eso se llama estrategia»
- «A eso se le llama estrategia»

¿Ambas son correctas? ¿Cúando hay que usar «le» y cúando no?

¿Sería igual la traducción a inglés?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prácticamente no hay diferencia entre:

- Eso se llama estrategia.
- A eso se le llama estrategia.

La segunda oración podría ser algo más enfática (a eso, y no a otra cosa), aunque es cierto que "eso" también puede ser enfático (eso, y no aquello).

El motivo por el cual se duplica el complemento indirecto (el verbo "llamar", a diferencia de "call" en inglés, no lleva complemento directo sino indirecto) puede encontrarse [en esta página](http://www.hispanoteca.eu/Gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Complementos%20-%20redundancia%20pronominal.htm) referida a la redundancia pronominal:

DUPLICADO DEL COMPLEMENTO INDIRECTO ANTEPUESTO AL VERBO

Si el complemento indirecto se antepone al verbo por énfasis o topicalización, se ha de repetir la función de complemento indirecto con el pronombre personal átono (clítico) correspondiente:

***A mi mujer le*** he regalado una pulsera para su cumpleaños.

***A los padres les*** voy a dar la noticia yo.

***A mis amigos les*** voy a mandar una invitación para mi cumpleaños.

***A mí me*** dio la mano y **a mi hijo le** dio un beso.

La traducción sería la misma en inglés:

- That is called "strategy".

or the more emphatic:

- That is what we call "strategy".

Comment: I suspect anyone in the UK or Ireland would say "Now that's what I call strategy" by analogy with the long series of records and CDs called "Now that's what I call music". They have released more than 100 compilations.